# PhpStorm: Can I add a new word to the global dictionary?

Tags: dictionary, phpstorm, spelling

I've added Italian dictionary to PhpStorm for spelling purpose.

I hate to readd this to *every* new project. Is there a way to keep the new dictionary added as default?

Also, when I add new word to dictionary, the word will be added only to project-level dict. Can I add to *global* (at PhpStorm level, I mean) dict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set IDE to save new words into Application-level dictionary instead of default Project-level.

`Settings/Preferences | Editor | Spelling | Use single dictionary for saving words`

[image]

Not super sure where that file is stored (since I prefer using Project-level), but it might be `options\cachedDictionary.xml` file. On Windows that would typically be in `C:\Users\USERNAME\.PhpStorm2019.3\config\` folder for current 2019.3 version (similar for Linux: `~/.PhpStorm2019.3/config/`; MacOS has a bit different path but the same file name).

Such dictionary is loaded once on IDE launch; you can add any words manually there, while IDE is closed, of course.